# Where is mongo.exe installed by default on ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to find the path to mongo.exe after following the https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.252350281.1547134441.1490924163

Tutorial.

However, it appears that the mongo.exe file is no where to be found?

Does anyone know the default directory that this file installs into? I've googled everywhere for an answer and have not seen any results either.

The reason I am doing this is to connect it to intellij.

Comment: there is no such things like `exe`'s on an ubuntu

Comment: @DarkBee Then why if I install the zip of the "pre-compiled version" I can get mongo.exe?

Comment: @DarkBee
https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community

Referring to this.

Comment: @DarkBee it defaults to usr/bin/mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file defaults to usr/bin/mongo.exe

Answer (score 1):

After successful installation, the executable defaults to /usr/bin/mongod .